# Link element tags are disabled when a background image is set

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, django

I've got this base.html from which other html documents extend

**base.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <--!some css links and jquery source headers-->
  <style>
   {% block style %}
     .container{
       position: relative;
     }
   {% endblock style %}
  </style>
 </head>
 <body>
   <div class="container">
    {% block breadcrumb %}{% endblock breadcrumb %}
{% block content %}{% endblock content %}
   </div>
 </body>
  
  <script type="text/JavaScript">
   {% block script %}
    var imgName = "{% url 'img_file.png' %}";
    document.body.style.backgroundImage = "url('"+ imgName.src +"')";
   {% endblock script %}
  </script>
<\html>
```

a document that extends from base.html

**index.html**

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block breadcrumb %}
  <div class="nav nav-bar nav-bar-dark>
    <a href="some url"> some link</a>
  </div>
{% endblock %}
{% block content %}
  <form action="view-url" method="post">
    {{ form }}
    <input type="submit" class="btn" value"Submit">
  </form>
{% endblock %}
```

the submit input works well but the link (to some url) seems to be disabled. When I remove the background image from the base.html, the link works just fine. Any help on what I'm missing here please ,

Comment: Your Closing Tag for HEAD has incorrect Syntax.

Comment: thanks Twisty, I just noticed that, however, I don't think that's the reason, given that I use sublime text editor with html tag auto-complete features

Comment: I am sure it was not the root cause yet it was the first error I observed. Please provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example from the resulting HTML.